# ¿Como conectar archivos por MVC en ASP.VBscript?

Tags: mvc, asp, vbscript

Estoy intentando conectar 3 archivos de codigo por medio de MVC que estan en 3 carpetas diferentes (vista, modelo y controlador) y el codigo que esta en vista me conecta con el del controlador, pero el del controlador no me conecta con el del modelo... he intentado de todo pero me funciona.

Les dejo los codigos:

el de vista: (nombre:clase1.asp)

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sin t&iacute;tulo</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="../controlador/subclase1.asp">
<table width="252" border="1">
<tr>
  <td width="89">Numero 1 </td>
  <td width="147"><label>
    <input type="text" name="num1" />
  </label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Numero 2 </td>
  <td><label>
    <input type="text" name="num2" />
  </label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><label>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" />
  </label></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

el del controlador: (nombre:subclase1.asp)

```
<!-- #include file="../modelo/recibirclase1.asp" -->
<%
num1=cINt(request.Form("num1"))
num2=cINt(request.Form("num2"))
set objeto = new ejemplo
objeto.suma num1, num2
response.Write(objeto.devolver)
%>
```

el del modelo: (recibirclase1.asp)

```
<%
class ejemplo

public resultado

public function suma(num1, num2)
resultado=num1+num2
end function

public function devolver()
devolver=resultado
end function

end class 
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré resolverlo colocando en el archivo controlador:

```
<!--#include virtual="/ejemploclases/modelo/recibirclase1.asp" -->
```

en donde:

ejemploclases: es la carpeta raiz (que contiene las carpetas modelo, vista y controlador)

modelo: la carpeta que contiene el archivo de las clases

recibirclase1.asp: que es el archivo que contiene la clase